# Is it possible to simulate the electric power output of a linear alternator using finite element analysis software?If yes, which?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, generator, linear-motors

We need to build a small (1-2W) linear alternator for a project in engineering school. Is it possible to use finite element software to finetune our design instead of actually building real life models? If yes, which software should we use? We are using AutoCAD fusion 360 to design our 3D-model.

Comment: For that sort of problem I'd suggest Comsol Electromagnetics.  You could also use the electromagnetic modules sold by Simulia or Ansys.

Comment: As the other comment says, you can, but if you have no experience of FEA this isn't the best problem to start learning, especially if you hoped you could couple a mechanical dynamic analysis of the device to its electromagnetic behaviour!

Comment: Both answers are very helpful, thank you! We will be sure to check those software packages! @alephzero how so? A linear alternator design seems to be quite simple? Also what problems would you recommend to learn the 'ins and outs' of the simulation software?